# Powershell script to extract the data from database using the data in input file and save the results in csv file

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

SCRIPT TO EXTRACT THE ALL  DETAILS

```
    #Variable to hold variable.
    $SQLServer = "XXXX"
    $SQLDBName = "XXXX"
    #Customer data input file path
    $InputFile = "F:\\CData.csv"
    # Reading the data in input file
    $InputFileContents = Get-Content -Path $InputFile
    #SQL Query for periodic payments.
    $SqlQuery = "SELECT ID,
    FROM \[XXXX\].\[dbo\].\[XXXX\] WITH(NOLOCK) where PSTATUS = 'F' AND Number IN  ($InputFileContents) ORDER BY Number"
    $SqlConnection = New- Objectsystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;Integrated  Security=True")
    $SqlConnection.Open()
    $SqlCmd = New-ObjectSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlQuery, $SqlConnection)
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($SqlCmd)
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $Sqlconnection.Close() 
    # Extracts are saving to CSV fil
    $DataSet.Tables\[0\] | Export-Csv "F:\\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 
    # Get the current date and time
    $dateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd-hh-mm-ss"
    # Add the date and time stamp to the file name
    $fileName = "F:\\output$dateTime.csv"
    # Move the file to new file date & time
    Move-Item "F:\\output.csv.csv" $fileName
```

I tried above script but i am getting below error while running it
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near ')'."
At F:\period.ps1:17 char:1

- $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
  ```

Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At F:\period.ps1:20 char:22

- $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv "F:\output.c ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo
  mmand
  ```

Comment: `SELECT ID,    FROM \[XXXX\].\[dbo\].\[XXXX\] WITH(NOLOCK)` looks fishy. You have a comma which shouldn't be there, not counting the weird slashes

Comment: And what is the value of `$InputFileContents`

Comment: PowerShell doesn't use the reverse solidus \ as its escape character in string literals. You might find removing some of them will clear up your error.

Comment: HI Siggemannen & Charlieface, Extra values are added while copying the code actual query is  SELECT ID
    FROM [XXXX\].[dbo].[XXXX] WITH(NOLOCK) where PSTATUS = 'F' AND Number IN  ($InputFileContents) ORDER BY Number" And $InputFileContents variable will have data of input file which i am passing. PFB    $InputFile = "F:\CData.csv"
    # Reading the data in input file
    $InputFileContents = Get-Content -Path $InputFile